Story or book from the 80s or 90s that had genetically created humans who could grow teeth and eat people
I ran across this story or book from the 80s or 90s while staying at a hotel/ski resort, and I've recently started re-reading old sci-fi books. All I really remember is that there were some people on the run from a government agent who had control of a small squad of genetically engineered men and women. They looked normal but could shapeshift a little (at least their teeth) and ate people. I specifically remember a scene in a nightclub where one of the women is slow dancing with a man but is actually eating his neck/shoulder.
They weren't vampires; it was a whole mouth of teeth—some kind of lab creation or mutant like a shark/human or something similarly predatory and carnivorous. I picked up Almost Human by James V. Smith, but I flipped through most of the book looking for anything I remembered, and it wasn't the story I recall. I think it was a whole novel, but it might have been a short story in an anthology. Long shot, but if anyone has a clue...

Technically, almost all of us can grow teeth and eat people.

Wanted to upvote this or give a 'like' :)  But it doesn't actually add anything of value to the post... and that appears to be my only option.

Was there some kind of mind-control going on, also? Seems like otherwise the guy would be screaming a bit.

The plot sounds like something that Dean Koontz would have written.

Does sound like Dean Koontz, but it wasn't in any of the summaries I read of his works.

And I think the guy in the nightclub was dead from the first bite, otherwise yeah that scene would have escalated more quickly...

I'm sure my Odd Thomas set is in the stack of boxes I'm moving out of a storage unit right now, but a review of "Odd Interlude" might match some things. No mention of a nightclub though: "the Harmony family who are trapped and being controlled by strangely powerful man by the name of Dr. Hiskott" and "with secret government research facilities, artificial intelligence, alien artifacts and DNA, and the horrifying result of that DNA’s mix with an already off-kilter scientist."

I don't think the Odd Thomas series is it, but I'll check that out - I did like the movie, never read any of the actual books. The name Hiskott does sound familiar somehow.

James V. Smith, Jr. series "Beastmaker, Beaststalker, Almost Human" is so close but wasn’t the book I remember. It’s 90% or more of the same idea & same feel but none of the trilogy were correct.
Still looking…
